# Unit testing accessors (getters and setters)

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, accessor, getter-setter

Given the following methods:

```
public function setFoo($foo) {
    $this->_foo = $foo;
    return $this;
}

public function getFoo() {
    return $this->_foo;
}
```

Assuming, they may be changed to be more complex in the future:

- How would you write unit tests for those methods?
- Just one test method?
- Should I skip those tests?
- What about code coverage?
- How about `@covers` annotation?
- Maybe some universal test method to implement in the abstract test case?

(I use Netbeans 7)

This seems like a waste of time, but I wouldn't mind if IDE would generate those test methods automatically.

To [qoute from the comment of Sebastian Bergman's blog](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html):

> (it's like testing getters and setters -- fail!). In any case, if they were to fail; wouldn't the methods that depend on on them fail?

So, what about the code coverage?

Comment: If you omit the tests (I would), you'll need to make sure to mark some other tests that call them with the appropriate `@covers` annotations. I sometimes combine these with `testConstruct()` and move on. As we all know, "accessors are evil!" ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should unit tests be written for getter and setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197370/should-unit-tests-be-written-for-getter-and-setters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good Question,

i usually try not to test getters&setters directly since i see a greater benefit in testing only the methods that actually *do* something.

Especially when not using TDD this has the added benefit of showing me setters that i don't use in my unittests showing me that ether my tests are incomplete or that the setter is not used/needed. "If i can execute all the "real" code without using that setter why is it there."

When using fluent setter i sometimes write a test checking the 'fluent' part of the setters but usually that is covered in other tests.

To answer your list:

- Just one test method?

<strike>That is my least favorite option. All or none. Testing only one is not easy for other people to understand and looks 'random' or needs to be documented in a way.</strike>

Edit after comment:

Yes, for "trivial" get/set testing I'd only use one method per property *maybe* depending on the case even only one method for the whole class (for value objects with many getters and setters I don't want to write/maintain many tests)

- How would you write unit tests for those methods?
- Should I skip those tests?

I wouldn't skip them. *Maybe* the getters depending on how many you have (i tend to write only getters i actually need) but the task of having a class completely covered shouldn't fail because of getters.

- What about code coverage?
- How about @covers annotation?

With `@covers` my take is always "use it everywhere or don't use it at all". Mixing the two 'styles' of testing takes away some of the benefits of the annotation and looks 'unfinished' to me.

- Maybe some universal test method to implement in the abstract test case?

For something like value objects that could work nicely. It might break (or gets more complicated) once you pass in objects / array with type hinting but I'd presonally prefer it over writing manual tests for 500 getters and setters.

Comment: By saying: *Just one test method?* I ment test both setter and getter in one method, not just to test one of them. Any code examples?

Comment: Edited the answer a little. I don't have a code sample at hand (since i mostly don't test the getters/setters directly) but i can write something up if you give me a hint in which direction to go or what kind of example you'd like to see

Comment: Thanks for the update. When you test both of the accessors in one method, how do you name it and how do you let know to the code coverage which methods this test covers? Annotation? Then what about annotations in other test methods? (Usually I don't use them at all).

Comment: Some people name it testGetSetProperty, some testAccessProperty and i've seen testProperty too. As long as it is consistent i don't really care, something like that. For `@covers` just list both/all methods in the tests docblock like here in phpunits own tests https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.5/Tests/Framework/ConstraintTest.php -- Btw: You can find some people to talk about phpunit in the #phpunit FreenodeIrc or in the `PHP` chat on SO too :)

Answer (score 8):

If you do TDD you should write a test for getter and setter. too. Do not
write a single line of code without a test for it - even if your code is
very simple.

Its a kind of religious war to use a tandem of getter and setter for
your test or to isolate each by accessing protected class members using
your unit test framework capabilities. As a black box tester i prefer to
tie my unit test code to the public api instead of tie it to the
concrete implementation details. I expect change. I want to encourage
the developers to refactor existing code. And class internals should not
effect "external code" (unit tests in this case). I don want to break
unit tests when internals change, i want them to break when the public
api changes or when behavior changes. Ok, ok, in case of a failing unit
test do not pin-point to the one-and-only source of problem. I do have
to look in the getter AND the setter to figure out what caused the
problem. Most of the time your getter is very simple (less then 5 lines
of code: e.g. a return and an optional null-check with an exception). So
checking this first is no big deal and not time consuming. And checking
the happy path of the setter is most of the time only a little more
complex (even if you have some validation checks).

Try to isolate your test cases - write a test for a SUT (Subject under
test) that validates its correctness without reley on other methods
(except my example above). The more you isolate the test, the more your
tests spot the problem.

Depending on your test strategy you may be want to cover happy path only
(pragmatic programmer). Or sad pathes, too. I prefer to cover all
execution pathes. When i think i discovered all execution pathes i check
code coverage to identify dead code (not to identify if there are
uncovered execution pathes - 100% code coverage is a missleading indicator).

It is best practice for black box testers to use phpunit in strict mode
and to use @covers to hide collateral coverage.

When you write unit test your test on class A should be executed independent from class B. So your unit tests for class A should not call / cover method of class B.

If you want to identify obsolete getter/setter and other "dead" methods (which are not used by production code) use static code analysis for that. The metric you are interested in is called "Afferent coupling at method level (MethodCa)". Unfortunately this metric (ca) is not available at method-level in PHP Depend (see: http://pdepend.org/documentation/software-metrics/index.html and http://pdepend.org/documentation/software-metrics/afferent-coupling.html). If you realy need it, feel free to contribute it to PHP Depend. An option to exclude calls from the same class would be helpful to get a result without "collateral" calls. If you identify a "dead method" try to figure out if it is meant to be used in near future (the counterpart for an other method that has a @depricated annotation) else remove it. In case it is used in the same class only, make it privat / protected. Do not apply this rule to library code.

Plan B:
If you have acceptance tests (integration test, regression test, etc.) you can run that test without running unit tests at the same time and without phpunits strict mode. This can result in a very similar code coverage result as if you had analysed your production code. But in most cases your non-unit tests are not as strong as your production code is. It depends on your discipline if this plan B is "equal enought" to production code to get a meaningful result.

Further reading:
- Book: Pragmatic Programmer
- Book: Clean Code

Comment: @AnonymousDownvoter: When you downvote, please let me know why you think this post was not helpful or wrong. Leave a comment, please.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common question but strangely can't find a dupe on SO.

You could write unit tests for accessors but the majority of practioners do not. i.e. if the accessors do not have any custom logic, I would not write unit tests to verify if field access works.
Instead I would rely on the consumers of these accessors to ensure that the accessors work. e.g. If getFoo and setFoo don't work, the callers of these method should break. So by writing unit tests for the calling methods, the accessors get verified.

This also means that code coverage should not be a problem. If you find accessors that are not covered after all test suites are run, maybe they are redundant / unused. Delete them.

Try to write a test that illustrates a scenario where a client will use that accessor. e.g. The below snippet shows how the Tooltip (property) for the Pause Button toggles based on its current mode.

```
[Test]
public void UpdatesTogglePauseTooltipBasedOnState()
{
    Assert.That(_mainViewModel.TogglePauseTooltip, Is.EqualTo(Strings.Main_PauseAllBeacons));

    _mainViewModel.TogglePauseCommand.Execute(null);
    Assert.That(_mainViewModel.TogglePauseTooltip, Is.EqualTo(Strings.Main_ResumeAllBeacons));

    _mainViewModel.TogglePauseCommand.Execute(null);
    Assert.That(_mainViewModel.TogglePauseTooltip, Is.EqualTo(Strings.Main_PauseAllBeacons));
}
```

Comment: There are [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[unit-testing]+getters+setters), but none of them provides examples how to actually write the code.