# How do you unit test a function that "resets" an object?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

Let's say you have a class that has some arbitrary attributes:

```dart
class Data {
  String a = '';
  int b = 0;
  bool c = false;
  SomeObject d = SomeObject();
}
```

Let's also say *somewhere* you have a function that you want to reset most *but not all* of this `Data` object's attributes to those which do not correlate to the object constructor's default values.

```dart
Data data = Data();

...

void resetData() {
  data = data
    ..a='reset'
    ..b=42
    ..c=true;
    // We want to retain [d]'s state, for whatever reason.
}
```

How do you go about unit testing this behavior?

You could have a unit test that sets each attribute of `Data` to something entirely different from whatever the reset's default values are and verify that all of the relevant fields change, but that's 1) incredibly brittle and 2) defeats the purpose of what unit testing is for. If you added another object `e` that's supposed to be reset as well, but you forgot to add it to the `resetData` function, you almost certainly forgot to add it to the unit test as well. The unit test would then be providing no value, since the behavior would be broken but you would not be alerted to it.

Using reflection/introspection through `dart:mirrors` is an option by testing that each of that object's variables are indeed different (other than `d`), but `dart:mirrors` does not work with AngularDart so users of that are left high and dry.

I also couldn't find any libraries that could "fuzz" objects by seeding the object with garbage values, so not entirely sure how to proceed (or if I should even be wasting my time with this seemingly silly unit test).

Answer (score 0):

Your question goes in a similar direction as the question, whether getters and setters should be unit-tested (see [Should unit tests be written for getter and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197370/should-unit-tests-be-written-for-getter-and-setters)).  Your code example for method `resetData` is, in a sense, even more trivial than setters, because the attributes are assigned constants rather than parameter values.

And, the unit-tests that test the correct setting of the respective attribute would just duplicate that value from the code.  The likelihood of findings bugs with such tests is low.  And, having a second developer look at the tests is not better than having the second developer review the code itself - a code review would even be a better use of development time.  The tests might have a bit of value as regression tests, but again, in most cases where changes are made to the code, the tests have to be maintained just to follow the code changes.

Therefore, similar as for getters and setters and trivial constructors, I would recommend not to write specific tests for `resetData`, but instead try to make `resetData` part of some (slightly) larger test scenario by testing the impact of `resetData` on subsequent computations:

```
// Setup:
Data data = Data(); // Construction
... // some calculation on data (optional)

// Exercise:
resetData()
... // some calculation on data

// Verify:
...
```

After all, there should be a reason from a user's perspective why `resetData` assigns those attributes their specific values.  These user focused scenarios could help to make useful tests.  (The name `resetData`, btw., violates the principle of least surprise because people will assume that it resets the values to the initial value.)

The other problem you describe (unit-tests don't tell you that you have not updated `resetData` if a new attribute was added) indicates you are expecting too much from unit-testing: This phenomenon is not limited to trivial functionality.  If you add an attribute and forget to update some complex function to make use of it, plus you leave the tests as they are, then the tests will also continue to pass.

You could think of clever tricks, like, keeping and comparing the list of attributes that were known at the moment the method was written against the current list of attributes (obtained using introspection), but that seems like overkill to me - unless you are developing safety critical code, which I believe `dart` might not be designed for.